# Can i dual boot windows 7 (x64) with Ubuntu 11.10 in Sony VAIO EA36?

Tags: 11.10

Yes, the question same on the title.
Can I ?
Are you there using Sony VAIO EA36 notebook? I wondering to install ubuntu 11.10 alongside windows.
If can, tell me what things (such as: repair disk) must i do to preparing install the ubuntu?

Please answer soonly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply download the .iso file, burn the image to the CD, boot from it, and select the 'install' option when the choice appears. There will be an option to 'install alongside Windows' which you should select. For more detailed instructions look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Comment: yes, I know how to install. but can i applying ubuntu to my vaio ea36? because the processor was using in my vaio is intel core i5 560m and supporting 64bit, and then the ubuntu i was buy is 32bit...

Comment: on 64 bit processor u can install 32 bit os & 64 bit os ... both will work properly , but its better to install 64 bit os on 64 bit processor

Comment: Ubuntu has both 64bit OS & 32bit OS > the choice is your's